# Creating a 3d vector with 2 given points linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

In this problem in my linear algebra textbook,

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMlpt.png)

I'm asked to determine the vector in R3 that represents the velocity of the airplane.

This is the solution

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJy45.png)

I understand where the 150sqrt(3) and 10 come from, but not the 150. A friend tells me it's because 300sin(30degrees), but why exactly do I need this sine?

Comment: Once you explain how you arrived at $150\sqrt3$ from the given data $300$ mph and $30^\circ$, you should see it.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution vector is given by its x-, y- and z-components as
$$(x,y,z)^T = (300 mph \sin(30 deg), 300 mph \cos(30 deg), 10 mph) = (150, 150 \sqrt{3}, 10)mph.$$ The sine of 30 degrees multiplies the length of the ground speed to give you the short side of the triangle (parallel to the x-axis). Similarly, the cosine of 30 degrees multiplies the length of the ground speed to give you the long side of the triangle (parallel to the y-axis).